# Mongoose: $inc not incrementing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

It seems like there were couple of similar posts, but none of the previous examples are the case of mine.

Currently, I have this:

```
 Item.findOneAndUpdate({ name: item }, { $inc: { count: 1 } }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("UPDATED: " + data);
        });

Search.findOneAndUpdate({ url: title }, { $inc: {totalCount: 1} }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("UPDATED: " + data);
        });
```

The first **findOneAndUpdate()** call to the **Item** model increments correctly.

However, the second **findOneAndUpdate()** call to the **Search** model does not increment the **totalCount** value.

It does not cause any errors, and the call back function returns the document correctly.

---

**So far I have tried with unsuccessful results:**

- Quoting the key ("totalCount": 1) -- I am aware this is equivalent to the original statement
- Removing the first F.O.A.U call to the Item model to see if two F.O.A.U calls are causing the problem.

---

**None of the above attempts worked, and I have no idea what the cause of this problem is.**

Comment: Check if `totalCount` is infact an integer

Comment: yes, I have double checked and it is int 32. The Search model is a globally declared model, which I have imported in the file. Can this cause the problem?

Comment: Can you show the definition of the model?

Comment: @gaganshera You were right! I forgot to define the key in the Schema, therefore the model was not updated correctly. Thank you!